# SUM function works fine in one sheet, but not the other?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I asked this before but I can't for the life of me find that question, so I just have to assume it dissolved into the ether.

I have this SUM function **=SUM(QUERY($A$1:$B, "SELECT B WHERE A = '" & "s" & "'", 0))** that works just fine when used on one sheet, but not on another sheet in the same spreadsheet. In the other spreadsheet, it returns a zero rather than the total that it's supposed to. Through some experimenting, I've found that reducing the query search range seems to fix the problem, but that is unhelpful to me as the new range is smaller than what I need. If anyone knows anything about this or any possible fixes, some help would be super appreciated!

Here is a copy of the spreadsheet in question, all cells containing the formula are highlighted yellow: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bNmDYdUw-FU4wWTShV1cijtOt9l7McvktgAoDELbwQ8/edit?usp=sharing

If any more info is needed feel free to ask! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your ***K Column*** formula. The formula returning text instead of numeric number which causing trouble `QUERY()` formula. Change this formula `=IF((E2*F2*H2)>0, Roundup(((E2/F2)+(E2/H2))/2, 3), "-")` to

```
=IF((E2*F2*H2)>0, Roundup(((E2/F2)+(E2/H2))/2, 3), 0)
```

You can directly use `avg()` function to query formula to get average. Try-

```
=QUERY($B$2:$M, "SELECT avg(K) WHERE B = 's' label avg(K) ''", 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful! Though if I may ask, what does the "label avg(K)" part do? I am relatively new to using google sheets and am still finding a million new bits and bobs to play with lol. Thanks!

Comment: @0SquishCat0 it removes the header/label. run this in some empty column and you will see: `=QUERY($B$2:$M, "SELECT avg(K) WHERE B = 's'")`

Comment: @0SquishCat0 `label` clause actually set header/label for column. Suppose `label avg(K) 'Average'` will set label as Average for result column. `label avg(K) ''` means empty label.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
="Average: "&AVERAGEIF(B2:B, "s", K2:K)
```

[image]